# Polymorphism with Abstract using Rectangle & Circle Shape Classes

Tags: java

I am having trouble. Im suppose to draw rectangle and circle shapes using a test program. but I run it, It prints no values. I wonder should I set Values for each shape. I need help on this.

This is the Figure class

```
public abstract class Figure{
    private int X, Y; // the center of the object.
    private String name;
    private static int numberOfShapes=0;

    public Figure(){
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        name = "none";
    }
    public Figure(int a, int b, String n){
        setX(a);
        setY(b);
        setName(n);
        numberOfShapes++;
    }
    public void setX(int a){X = a;}
    public void setY(int b){Y = b;}
    public void setName(String n){name = n;}
    public int getX(){return X;}
    public int getY(){return Y;}
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public static int getNumberOfShapes(){return numberOfShapes;}
    public abstract void erase();
    public abstract void draw();
    public void center(){
        System.out.println("\nIn Figure. Centering at ("+getX()+","+getY()+")");
    }
```

This is my Rectangle Class

```
public class Rectangle extends Figure {
    int length, height;
    public Rectangle(){
        super(0,0,"none");
        //setLength(0);
        //setHeight(0);
    }
    public Rectangle(String n,int a, int b, int h,int l){
        super(a,b,n);
        setLength(l);
        setHeight(h);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "In Rectangle Drawing " + getName() + " centered at (" + getX() + "," + getY() + ") Length " + getLength() + " height " + getHeight();
    }
    public void erase(){
        System.out.println("In Rectangle erasing");
    }
    public void draw(){
        center();
        erase();
        System.out.println(""+this);
    }

    public void setLength(int l){length = l;}
    public void setHeight(int h){height = h;}
    public int getLength(){return length;}
    public int getHeight(){return height;}

}
```

My Circle Class

```
public class Circle extends Figure {
        private double Radius;
        public Circle(){
            super(0,0,"none");
        }
        public Circle(String n, int a, int b){
            super(a,b,n);
        }
        public double getArea() {
            return Math.PI * Radius * Radius;
        }

        public void setRadius(double r){
            Radius = r;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return "In Circle Drawing "+getName()+" centered at ("+getX()+","+getY()+") Area "+getArea();
        }
        public void erase(){
            System.out.println("In Circle erasing");
        }
        public void draw(){
            erase();
            System.out.println(""+this);
        }
        public void setRadius(int r){Radius = r;}
        public double getRadius(){return Radius;}



}
```

This is my Test Class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Testshape{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        //Rectangle ry = new Rectangle();




        System.out.println("In Rectangle erasing");
        System.out.println(r);




    }
}
```

MY OUTPUT FORMAT SUPPOSE TO BE LIKE THIS:

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ceD.png)

Comment: Have you tried to `draw()` it inside your test class?

Comment: You are never calling any other methods other than the constructors. Why would you expect it to print anything?

Comment: @RamisWachtler my `draw()` is void so it wouldn't return any of my values. I tried to do `System.out.println(r.toString());` to see what my returns.

Comment: This is the result `In Rectangle erasing
In Rectangle Drawing none centered at (0,0) Length 0 height 0`

Comment: @mvd I already declare the return values in my `toString()` methods. Should I just print that method is I can see what are the values is printing?

Comment: where do you set the values of `x` and `y` to something else than `0`?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle the `x` and `y` values are in my Figure class. Shouldnt my values increase by one. I added `numberofShapes++` under my `public Figure(int a, int b, String n)` method

Comment: @KashadT: but you call the other constructor which does not increment the values.

Answer (score 0):

Call the **toString()** method of your classes to get the output.
You are not passing any parameter to the constructor method, so I wonder if this even compiles. A rectangle's opposite sides are congruent, equal width and length on opposite side.

```
public class Testshape{
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle("Rectangle",length, width);

    System.out.println("In Rectangle erasing");
    System.out.println(r.toString());

}
```

Comment: I did calling the `toString` method and this is my result:

Comment: `In Rectangle erasing
In Rectangle Drawing none centered at (0,0) Length 0 height 0`

Comment: That's because of the way you are passing your parameter to constructor super(0,0,"none"); Where your a and b is always zero. So in your output ,you will get centered at 0. Fix those errors and

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are missing the call to the `draw()` method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Testshape{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        //Rectangle ry = new Rectangle();

        r.draw();


        System.out.println("In Rectangle erasing");
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and this was my result: `In Rectangle erasing
In Rectangle Drawing none centered at (0,0) Length 0 height 0
In Rectangle erasing
In Rectangle Drawing none centered at (0,0) Length 0 height 0`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any message call on your function.

You might to call the function for the action, you have only instatiated the class and your constructor is not doing anything that prints.